# Inequality Constrained Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am working on the question displayed below. I am not sure if I understand it correctly and I am looking for some input.

[image: Question]

So, I am asked

> Why is $x^*$ a local maximum for $f$ subject to the set of constraints $g_j(x) \leq 0, j \in A(x^*)$ ?

I think the question is asking why the local maximum $f$ is subject to the set of constraints $g_j(x) \leq 0, j \in A(x^*)$ as supposed to $j \notin A(x^*)$?

For every $g_j(x)$ with  $j \notin A(x^*)$, we have $g_j(x) < 0$. If $g_j(x) < 0$ then complementary slackness dictates that $\lambda_j = 0$ and as such $g_j(x)$ is nonbinding in the solution. The maximum of $f$ is only subject to active constraints.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write down the feasible sets of your original problem and of the new problem. One of them is included in the other one, however, this is not the direction you need for your statement. But the converse inclusion holds in a neighborhood of $x$, i.e., if you intersect both feasible sets with a suitable neighborhood of $x$.